# jqgrid set the width of the edit dialog

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid and I have a edit dialog coming up: I don't want the default width of 300 but instead 700.

I've search and found some examples and I changed my code to:

```
$("#list").navGrid('#pager', { edit: false, add: true, del: true, search: false }, {width:700}, {}, { url: "/../Invoice/DeleteInvoiceLine" });
```

This should change the width to 700? It doesn't?

Comment: Although, the thread is quiet old, just wondering whether you remember it or not. This is really helpful for me but question, why you have used the `{ url: "/../Invoice/DeleteInvoiceLine" }`. Appreciate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are separate settings for Add and Edit dialog. You use `edit: false, add: true` options of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition), but set the width of the Add dialog only. If you really need to have only Add dialog

```js
$("#grid_id").navGrid('#gridpager', { edit: false, search: false },
    {/*Edit options*/}, { width: 700 }, { url: "/../Invoice/DeleteInvoiceLine" });
```

To have Edit dialog only you can use

```js
$("#grid_id").navGrid('#gridpager', { add: false, search: false },
    { width: 700 }, {/*Add options*/}, { url: "/../Invoice/DeleteInvoiceLine" });
```

If you need have both Add and Edit dialog with different options you should use [recreateForm: true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties) options additionally:

```js
$("#grid_id").navGrid('#gridpager', { search: false },
    { width: 700, recreateForm: true },
    { width: 600, recreateForm: true },
    { url: "/../Invoice/DeleteInvoiceLine" });
```